# uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Testing (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec2, sidekiq

I am using Sidekiq for background jobs.

I want to run background jobs in Test environment to test some features.

I have read the wiki of sidekiq https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing#testing-workers-inline

So I am trying to use that in my spec file but gives me error like

```
<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Testing (NameError)
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got It.

Just need to use `require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'` in spec_helper.rb

Thats it. No need to write `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!`

Answer (score 0):

Use updated `Sidekiq` gem version which is compatible with the Rails and ruby versions installed,

```
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 3.0.0'
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, Yes i have updated sidekiq with 2.15.0, after that i am getting an error like:
 included': uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Actor::Celluloid (NameError)

Comment: One reference I found that the issue has been fixed in 2.15.0. anyway, you may use the latest version. Or otherwise just use `gem sidekiq` in your Gemfile and do `bundle update`. Then check if the issue persists.